# USB drive not working on Windows after connecting it to Fedora

Tags: fedora, windows, usb-drive, fat

When I connect my USB with FAT file system to Fedora and after that when I try to connect it to my Windows 8 machine, it says that drive is "corrupted or data is unreadable".

This error does not show everytime. Sometimes the USB is recognised without any problem. So any solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Especially if the problem is on the Windows side, this question should probably be asked over at Super User instead of the Unix/Linux site

Comment: What if you change the file system to NTFS? Does the problem persist? Secondly, have you checked the drive for common errors?, i.e. `chkdsk u: /f` (where u is your USB drive)

Comment: I have already tried NTFS too.